# Static function leading to more static functions

Tags: c++

I have a class that has a few functions that are useful on their own, which are static. Now these functions depend on other functions that are not useful on their own (but don't interact with class member variables) but are also static, so they are private. Now I have a class with many non-static functions, and couple of static public functions and a few static private functions.

Is this good practice? (should I be making this a community wiki?)

Comment: it is not clear what do you mean by "useful/not useful on their own" - can you elaborate?

Comment: The static function is doing some heavy duty formatting, so I have broken it up. The user/client will call the heavy-duty function, which in turn relies on smaller functions which are not useful for the client at all and hence the functions are private (I am under the assumption that one of the uses of declaring a function private is to give the client a strong hint that this function is not intended to be used by anybody except the class/object itself).

Comment: I know why functions are made private or public :), it's "on their own" that confuses me. Actually, I am trying to figure out whether these functions should belong to the class, or can be free functions as @mkaes suggests. If they don't make use of static members, the only reason they belong to the class is scoping - meaning that they are conceptually part of class' services. Good e.g. is factory method, e.g. `Document::createDoc(Document::DocType)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you should declare those functions as free functions. If they do not need the members it should be not a big deal.
Maybe you should read this [article](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184401197). I found it very useful to improve my class designs.

Comment: Yeah, the only time I really find it useful to use static functions in classes is to get information about the class itself, singleton creation, or some kind of factory class that has access to private members/functions of another class that it creates.  Even then, the factory should be an instance so it can hold onto pointers or information about its created objects

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll read that article as soon as I find the time. I do have a question though. Considering I have a few functions that are not useful at all for the user (and are therefore private), how would I suggest that to the user with a free function?

Comment: @Samaursa: Put them in a `detail` namespace if you need them across multiple `.cpp` or just put them in the `.cpp` where they are used (in an unnamed namespace)
.

Comment: Put the free function in the .cpp file, so it doesn't appear in the .h

Comment: I second this. This is one advantage C++ has over languages like Java and C# that force you to put everything inside of a class definition. Here's another useful article in the same vein where Herb Sutter talks about the std::string interface: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm

Comment: @Samaursa: put them in the `.cpp` file, and tag them as `static`.

Answer (score 4):

That sounds good, and would work well. There are some things to consider though.

It may be possible to make the private static functions even more private. If you just placed them in the .cpp file as free functions (not in a class, but ideally in an 'unnamed namespace'), then they wouldn't make an appearance in the .h file. This would be advantageous because another .cpp file that uses your class wouldn't see these private static variables. That would make the compile time quicker. Also, it would leave you free to alter the functions in the .cpp file, and if you made any changes, other files using the .h file wouldn't need to be recompiled on every change because you wouldn't have to change the .h file to change these functions.

Secondly, sometimes static functions can cause the writing of unit tests to be trickier. If you have a class X that uses these static functions, it's tricky to isolate class X from the static functions if you want to test class X. If instead, you used non static methods and defined an interface class that the class you're writing derives from, you could more easily use 'inversion of control' and 'dependency injection' techniques to write unit tests for your classes. I won't explain those techniques here, as there are plenty of good descriptions already floating about the internet.

Comment: +1 Good points about using unnamed namespaces in the .cpp file and about unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. `static` function which has nothing to do with the class can be encapsulated either in an inner `class` or in a new `namepsace`. e.g

```
struct A
{
  struct Util  // can also be put outside in a namespace for others to use
  {
    static void Independent () { }
  };
  static void dependent ();
};
```

Comment: "Keep it simple" followed by an over-complicated solution.

Comment: @Tomalak, LOL.. anyways that was meant for better code organization.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the "many non-static functions" as well as probably you could split the class into some smaller entities related by inheritance or ideally being more independent and could be brought to the initial form by composition. Generally the word "many" is not a sign of good design.